# Why it is important to compute centers of hyperbolic components of Mandelbrot set?

Tags: polynomials, fractals, complex-dynamics

The problem of computing centers of [hyperbolic components of Mandelbrot set](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Mandelbrot_set#Hyperbolic_components) is a polynomial root-finding problem. It is also one of the test problems for polynomial root-finding solvers such as MPSolve. My question is why it is important to compute these points, especially for high orders?

Comment: You can't really understand the structure of the Mandelbrot set without identifying it's hyperbolic components and a fundamental step in doing that is solving those polynomials. So, I'd say that finding those points is no more or less important than understanding the Mandelbrot set in the first place. Is *that* important? I really don't know.

Answer (score 0):

It is :

- time consuming task
- with infinite complexity ( number of centers and periods have no limits)
  so it can be used as a benchmark for
- computers
- programs / algorithms / arbitrary precision libraries